# A pronoun for an industry can be female?

Tags: pronouns

In the movie *Iron Man* there is the following phrase:

> Today, Tony Stark has changed the face of the weapons industry by
>   ensuring freedom and protecting America and her interests around the
>   globe.

Why in this text "her" is used instead of "its"?

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204217/using-her-vs-its-to-refer-to-a-country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the industry,  but the country ("America").

Countries are one of the things (like ships and cars) which are sometimes referred to with female pronouns.